# SherlockFragmentActivity set view elements in code

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm starting out with Android Development and created a SherlockActionBar based App.

Now I'm stuck with getting the widgets from the xml layout to set them in code.

Here's my class:

```
public class Streaming extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_streaming, container, false);

        // set widgets here..

        return fragmentView;

    }

}
```

and the xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

The problem is I can't set the view itself. The background is not even changing to #FFFFFF

Comment: First of all, it's `wrap_content` and there's no source. Are you setting it from code? Secondly, what are the insides of `R.layout.view_streaming`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a standard `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}` method and set a view from there, just as you would in a simple `Activity` class ( `setContentView(R.layout.view_streaming);` ). There is no need for `onCreateView()` in `SherlockFragmentActivity`. You would use it in `SherlockFragment` or `SherlockListFragment` for example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was messing up a few things. Had to implement SherlockFragment instead of SFActivity.. So in this way onCreateView() gets triggered correctly.